# tmux: How do I make a session 'dead' but not destroy it

Tags: tmux

I have `set-option -g remain-on-exit on` in my `.tmux.conf`, and so my tmux panes become zombies after their command exits, allowing me to easily restart them if needed:
[image]
I want a way to kill a session this way. Using `tmux kill-session -t ...` normally 'kills' the session, while I want to make the session a 'zombie', like the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a session without any panes. You have to leave at least one pane.

If you know the session name, you can get its windows or panes with `list-windows` or `list-panes`.

But - since you have set `remain-on-exit` globally, why does it matter if the sessions are destroyed?

Edit: `respawn-pane -kt sth:0.0 true` is the solution.

Comment: When I use `tmux kill-session -t sth`, that session doesn't remain any more. `tmux list-panes -st sth` returns `0.0: [127x35] [history 9/2000, 4065 bytes] %19 (active)` . How can I kill this pane?

Comment: But why does it matter if the session doesn't remain? What use is a session with no panes? If you kill the only pane in a session, the session will be destroyed too, if you want to keep the session then you will need to leave at least one pane.

Comment: I updated the question. I hope it's now more understandable.

Comment: You want to kill what is in the pane and make it dead? The easiest way is to use `respawn-pane` with something that will immediately exit, for example `respawn-pane -kt sth:0.0 true`. Alternatively you could use `lsp -st sth -F '#{pane_pid}'` to get the PIDs and kill them. Or do similar with `pane_tty` and use `ps` to get all the PIDs for that tty.

Comment: Note if you want to kill all panes in a window you can just `respawn-window -kt sth:0 true` instead of `respawn-pane` every pane.

Comment: That's what I needed! Thanks! Put the last comment in the answer and I'll accept it.